# sh shell: how to use $1 inside quotes

Tags: shell, parameter

I am using this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
    echo "wrong syntax"
    echo "ct_cmp.sh <label1> <label2> [<file_extension>]"
else
    if [ $# -eq 2 ]
    then
        cleartool find . -version 'lbtype($1) && \!lbtype($2)' -print
    fi
fi
```

but get this result:

cleartool:

```
Error: Invalid query: "lbtype($1) && \!lbtype($2)"
```

Answer (score 4):

The single quote will prevent the expansion of the parameters in:

```
'lbtype($1) && \!lbtype($2)'
```

It should work with `"'lbtype($1) && \!lbtype($2)'"`.

On a side note, one of my go-to tools when working on shell script is to validate them with shellcheck: https://www.shellcheck.net/ (also available in the standalone executable). Without surprise, it will tell you exactly the same thing about the simple quote.

Comment: `apt-get install chellcheck` to install on debian and derivatives.

Comment: Do you still need the single quotes?

Comment: I tried, but now i get this error message:
cleartool: Error: Unrecognized operator: "'lbtype".